# R: How to extract information from text between two key words and export to table?

Tags: r

I got a txt file in this way:

```
-- SMART RESULTS TEXTFORMAT --
USER_PROTEIN_ID = SAUSA300_RS14200
SMART_PROTEIN_ID = uniprot|Q5HCS9|Q5HCS9_STAAC
NUMBER_OF_FEATURES_FOUND=1
DOMAIN=transmembrane_domain
START=7
END=29
EVALUE=0
TYPE=INTRINSIC
STATUS=visible|OK
-- FINISHED --
-- SMART RESULTS TEXTFORMAT --
USER_PROTEIN_ID = SAUSA300_RS11975
SMART_PROTEIN_ID = uniprot|A6QJ58|A6QJ58_STAAE
NUMBER_OF_FEATURES_FOUND=0
-- FINISHED --
-- SMART RESULTS TEXTFORMAT --
USER_PROTEIN_ID = SAUSA300_RS14395
SMART_PROTEIN_ID = uniprot|Q2FDK5|SRAP_STAA3
NUMBER_OF_FEATURES_FOUND=1
DOMAIN=Pfam:Gram_pos_anchor
START=2221
END=2258
EVALUE=6e-08
TYPE=PFAM
STATUS=visible|OK
-- FINISHED --
```

What I want is to get information between "SMART RESULTS TEXTFORMAT" and "FINISHED" and export each part for different USER_PROTEIN_ID into each row in table.

Could any one provide some codes? I got some complicated ones by myself. It ended up in a dataframe, but don't know how to continue to export to each row in excel.

```
start="-- SMART RESULTS TEXTFORMAT --"
end="-- FINISHED --"
n=nrow(myfile)
index=c(1:n)
myfile=cbind(index,myfile)
starline=as.data.frame(grep(start,myfile[,2]))
endline=as.data.frame(grep(end,myfile[,2]))
indexlist=cbind(starline,endline)
newlist=character(length = n)
for (i in 1:n) {
 index1=indexlist[i,1]+1
 index2=indexlist[i,2]-1
newlist[i]=as.data.frame(as.data.frame(myfile[index1:index2,2]))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work nicely for you:

```
library("magrittr")
data <- split(txt, cumsum(grepl("-- SMART RESULTS TEXTFORMAT --", txt))) %>% 
  lapply(function(i) i[!grepl("-- SMART RESULTS TEXTFORMAT --|-- FINISHED --", i)]) %>% 
  lapply(function(i) {
    read.table(text = i, sep = "=", header = FALSE) %>% 
      t(.) %>% 
      tibble::as_tibble() %>% 
      magrittr::set_colnames(trimws(.[1, ])) %>% 
      slice(-1)
  }) %>% 
  plyr::rbind.fill()
```

For export, I would highly recommend `rio`:

```
rio::export(data, "data.xlsx")
```

Here is how I got the data (I write out the text and read it back it to simulate that part as well):

```
txt <- "-- SMART RESULTS TEXTFORMAT --
USER_PROTEIN_ID = SAUSA300_RS14200
SMART_PROTEIN_ID = uniprot|Q5HCS9|Q5HCS9_STAAC
NUMBER_OF_FEATURES_FOUND=1
DOMAIN=transmembrane_domain
START=7
END=29
EVALUE=0
TYPE=INTRINSIC
STATUS=visible|OK
-- FINISHED --
-- SMART RESULTS TEXTFORMAT --
USER_PROTEIN_ID = SAUSA300_RS11975
SMART_PROTEIN_ID = uniprot|A6QJ58|A6QJ58_STAAE
NUMBER_OF_FEATURES_FOUND=0
-- FINISHED --
-- SMART RESULTS TEXTFORMAT --
USER_PROTEIN_ID = SAUSA300_RS14395
SMART_PROTEIN_ID = uniprot|Q2FDK5|SRAP_STAA3
NUMBER_OF_FEATURES_FOUND=1
DOMAIN=Pfam:Gram_pos_anchor
START=2221
END=2258
EVALUE=6e-08
TYPE=PFAM
STATUS=visible|OK
-- FINISHED --"
writeLines(txt, "test.txt")
txt <- readLines("test.txt")
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I need! The format is really clear and can be easily used for next steps!

Comment: Hi, can i ask a stupid question? What is cumsum() in your answer for? I'm trying to understand every piece of the codes. Thanks!

Comment: It's not a stupid question! `split` needs a factor with groups to know where to cut a vector. When you use `grepl` you get `TRUE` when a string is found or `FALSE` when not. These are actually the same as `1` and `0`. `cumsum` is the cumulative sum. So when I go through the vector the sum for each element is `cumsum + 1` when the string is found or  `cumsum + 0` when not. This effectively creates a new vector with the length of your character vector that looks somewhat like that: `1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3`. Each number is then a group that can be used for splitting.

Answer (score 0):

The code you wrote looks fine.

For the excel export look at the [xlsx package](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/xlsx/versions/0.6.1)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, my problem is solved. My question is I can extract what i need but can't generate a nice output. I tried xlsx output but took year and killed the R.